# Are service fabric services entirely single-threaded?

Tags: asp.net-web-api, owin, azure-service-fabric

I'm trying to get to grips with service fabric and I'm struggling a little bit. Some questions:

- are all service fabric service instances single-threaded? I created a stateless web api, one instance, with a method that did a Task.Delay, then returned a string. Two requests to this service were served one after the other, not concurrently. So am I right in thinking then that the number of concurrent requests that can be served is purely a function of the service instance count in the application manifest? **Edit** Thinking about this, it is probably to do with the set up of OWIN Wep Api. Could it be it is blocking by session? I assumed there is no session by default?
- I have long-running operations that I need to perform in service fabric (that can take several hours). Is there a recommended pattern that I can use for this in service fabric? These are currently handled using a storage queue that triggers a webjob. Maybe something with Reliable Queues and a RunAsync loop?

Answer (score 1):

It seems you handled the first part so I will comment on the second part: "long-running operations".

We can see long running operations / workflows being handled far before service fabric came about. For this reason, we can build on the shoulders of giants by looking on the design patterns that software experts have been using for decades. For example, the famous and all inclusive [Process Manager](http://www.enterpriseintegrationpatterns.com/patterns/messaging/ProcessManager.html). Mind you that this pattern is sometimes an overkill. If it is in your case, just check out the rest of the related patterns in the Enterprise Integration Patterns book (by Gregor Hohpe).

As for the use of reliable collections, those are implementation details when choosing a data structure supporting the chosen design pattern.

I hope that helps

Answer (score 1):

With regards to your second point - It really depends on the nature of your long running task.

Is your long running task the kind of workload that runs on an isolated thread that depends on local OS/VM level resources and eventually comes back with a result (A)? or is it the kind of long running task that goes through stages and builds up a model of the result through a series of persisted state changes (B)?

From what I understand of Service Fabric, it isn't really designed for running long running workloads (A), but more for writing horizontally-scalable, highly-available systems.

If you were absolutely keen on using service fabric (and your kind of workload tends to be more like B than A) I would definitely find a way to break down those long running tasks that could be processed in parallel across the cluster. But even then, there is probably more appropriate technologies designed for this such as Azure Batch?

P.s. If you are going to put a long running process in the RunAsync method, you should design the workload so it is interruptable and its state can be persisted in a way that can be resumed from another node in the cluster

> In a stateful service, only the primary replica has write access to
>   state and thus is generally when the service is performing actual
>   work. The RunAsync method in a stateful service is executed only when
>   the stateful service replica is primary. The RunAsync method is
>   cancelled when a primary replica's role changes away from primary, as
>   well as during the close and abort events.

P.s.s Long running operations are the devil when trying to write scalable systems. Try and tackle that now and save yourself the future pain if possibe.

Comment: The processes are more like B. However they mostly involve IO with a very throttle-happy service (SharePoint Online). So I'm limited in how much I can  make the processing concurrent. The tasks are user-initiated also, so not really a batch process.

Answer (score 0):

To the first point - this is purely a client issue. Chrome saw my requests as indentical and so delayed the 2nd request until the 1st got a response. Varying the parameter of the requests allowed them to be served concurrently.